# Decoherence time for a voluntary action?

Tags: decoherence

In the thought experiment of [Laplace's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon), one talks about an omnipotent being who if he/she knows about all the initial conditions of this world (if the world is considered classical fundamentally) can predict the future and past with absolute determinism. In this hypothetical world, then there is no meaning of free will. Everything is predetermined with the set of initial condition defined. But quantum dynamics fundamentally govern our world. In the real world, we have free will.

Let's now say I perform a voluntary action that is determined by me alone and not influenced by anything else. This action can be in principle fully understood in terms of physical laws- as the action that I performed is coordinated by my brain and realized by my body and senses. Everything in this complex system (whole body) fundamentally is governed by the laws of physics, which are again fundamentally of quantum nature.

So my question is what the `decoherence time' for this action performed under free will? So what I mean by this is let say I decided to perform the same action again and started performing the action, but I want to ask now the timescale up to which I can interfere with this decision of mine (assuming my reflexes are instantaneous)?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is at all precise. If I decide to jump out of bed right now, I have a fraction of a second (if that) in which to change my mind. If I decide I will jump out of bed in half an hour's time I have half an hour in which to change my mind.

Comment: @gandalf61, what I meant is say I decided to do the action at time $t=t_0$ then upto what time $t=t_0-\delta t$ can I decide to change my decision? The decision to change my decision of performing the action is made instantaneously and is not pre-planned per se. I am interested in knowing this $\delta t$.

Answer (score 1):

Neither your decisions nor your actions are instantaneous. Your decisions take place over more than 0.001s since neurons fire at most 1000 times per second. A neuron will decohere in less than $10^{-13}$s so your decision takes longer than the decoherence time and you can't interfere with different versions of you that made different decisions:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907009

On free will what matters is criticise and replace your current ideas and priorities and quantum physics is only relevant to that to the extent that it allows the existence of solid matter, information processing, life and that sort of thing.